# Get number of weeks by month In year

Tags: java

I want to get the number of weeks by year. I have a wrong result with this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    cal.set(this.anneeActuelle, i, 1);
    nombreMaxSemaine = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Comment: nombreMaxSemaine = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);

Comment: Could provide an example of the wrong data you are receiving, and your expectation?

Comment: Do you want the number of the current week in the current YEAR [1;52] or the number of the current week in the current MONTH [1;4] ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for doing your work for you. You should tell us what’s wrong with your code and what result you want to get. Read how to ask a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: numberMaxWeek = c.getMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);  (53 )

Comment: and the sum off the result  is > then 53

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Original answer (see EDIT section below to the correct answer)**

The OP wants the maximum amount of weeks in a **MONTH**.
You can do it like [this](https://dzone.com/articles/handling-weeks-in-java-7-2)

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(calendar.isWeekDateSupported()) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
            for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
                int nombreMaxSemaine = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
                System.out.println("Current week number: " + nombreMaxSemaine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output  :

```
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
Current week number: 4
```

---

**EDIT**

As **Basil Bourque** said, the use of `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` APIs are deprecated and should be avoided.

Both APIs are known for making useless performance costs and contains bugs in their implementation. They have been replaced by the API `java.time.*` since JDK 8. The replacement of both APIs with `java.time.*` and the problems linked to those APIs are listed in [Java JSR-310 specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

**The correct answer to this question is** [Prim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56737871/5525384) **below.**

Comment: Wrong result  the sum of all week number that will be 48 and the result of c.getMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) is 53

Comment: The terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Avoid this class entirely. See the [correct Answer by Prim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56737871/642706).

Answer (score 7):

From Java 8+, you can easily get the number of weeks in a month using [YearMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) like that :

```
YearMonth.of(2019, Month.JULY).atEndOfMonth().get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth())
```

The use of the legacy `Calendar` class should be avoided (replaced by the new Date/Time Api in Java 8)

Comment: For Java 6 & 7, use the back-port of *java.time* found in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.